# ubuntu 18.04.2 ignoring hosts file for some domains (block ms, fb)

Tags: dns, facebook, hosts, microsoft

When configuring hosts file as such:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   brad-HP-Z420-Workstation
127.0.0.1   ethical.healthcare  
127.0.0.2   *.facebook.com
127.0.0.3   *.microsoft.com
```

facebook and microsoft still  correctly resolve even through icmp services, even after a reboot. Nsswitch seems configured correctly:

```
hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns myhostname
networks:       files
```

Note that if you try ethical.healthcare, at the time of this post, you will find a parked domain (mine) which correctly resolves on my machine to my apache instance. So it seems /etc/hosts is working for SOME domains, but not all. I also added 127.0.0.4 *wired.com to the above and it does not work either. Note I have rebooted the machine completely and this issue is still not resolved.

OK, thanks. I honestly thought wildcards were supported in *nix. Back to the old version, posted here in case anyone cares.

```
0.0.0.0 m.facebook.com
0.0.0.0 upload.facebook.com
0.0.0.0 apps.facebook.com
0.0.0.0 newsroom.fb.com
0.0.0.0 developers.facebook.com
0.0.0.0 touch.facebook.com
0.0.0.0 pixel.facebook.com
0.0.0.0 static.facebook.com
0.0.0.0 beta.facebook.com
0.0.0.0 graph.facebook.com
0.0.0.0 login.facebook.com
0.0.0.0 inyour.facebook.com
0.0.0.0 secure.facebook.com
0.0.0.0 latest.facebook.com
0.0.0.0 a-0001.a-msedge.net
0.0.0.0 a.ads1.msn.com
0.0.0.0 a.ads2.msn.com
0.0.0.0 ad.doubleclick.net
0.0.0.0 adnexus.net
0.0.0.0 adnxs.com
0.0.0.0 ads.msn.com
0.0.0.0 ads1.msads.net
0.0.0.0 ads1.msn.com
0.0.0.0 az361816.vo.msecnd.net
0.0.0.0 az512334.vo.msecnd.net
0.0.0.0 ca.telemetry.microsoft.com
0.0.0.0 cache.datamart.windows.com
0.0.0.0 choice.microsoft.com
0.0.0.0 choice.microsoft.com.nsatc.net
0.0.0.0 choice.microsoft.com.nstac.net
0.0.0.0 compatexchange.cloudapp.net
0.0.0.0 corp.sts.microsoft.com
0.0.0.0 corpext.msitadfs.glbdns2.microsoft.com
0.0.0.0 cs1.wpc.v0cdn.net
0.0.0.0 db3wns2011111.wns.windows.com
0.0.0.0 df.telemetry.microsoft.com
0.0.0.0 diagnostics.support.microsoft.com
0.0.0.0 fe2.update.microsoft.com.akadns.net
0.0.0.0 fe3.delivery.dsp.mp.microsoft.com.nsatc.net
0.0.0.0 feedback.microsoft-hohm.com
0.0.0.0 feedback.search.microsoft.com
0.0.0.0 feedback.windows.com
0.0.0.0 i1.services.social.microsoft.com
0.0.0.0 i1.services.social.microsoft.com.nsatc.net
0.0.0.0 msnbot-207-46-194-33.search.msn.com
0.0.0.0 oca.telemetry.microsoft.com
0.0.0.0 oca.telemetry.microsoft.com.nsatc.net
0.0.0.0 pre.footprintpredict.com
0.0.0.0 preview.msn.com
0.0.0.0 rad.msn.com
0.0.0.0 redir.metaservices.microsoft.com
0.0.0.0 reports.wes.df.telemetry.microsoft.com
0.0.0.0 s0.2mdn.net
0.0.0.0 services.wes.df.telemetry.microsoft.com
0.0.0.0 settings-sandbox.data.microsoft.com
0.0.0.0 settings-win.data.microsoft.com
0.0.0.0 settings.data.microsof.com
0.0.0.0 sls.update.microsoft.com.akadns.net
0.0.0.0 spynet2.microsoft.com
0.0.0.0 spynetalt.microsoft.com
0.0.0.0 sqm.df.telemetry.microsoft.com
0.0.0.0 sqm.telemetry.microsoft.com
0.0.0.0 sqm.telemetry.microsoft.com.nsatc.net
0.0.0.0 ssw.live.com
0.0.0.0 statsfe1.ws.microsoft.com
0.0.0.0 statsfe2.update.microsoft.com.akadns.net
0.0.0.0 statsfe2.ws.microsoft.com
0.0.0.0 survey.watson.microsoft.com
0.0.0.0 telecommand.telemetry.microsoft.com
0.0.0.0 telecommand.telemetry.microsoft.com.nsatc.net
0.0.0.0 telemetry.appex.bing.net
0.0.0.0 telemetry.microsoft.com
0.0.0.0 telemetry.urs.microsoft.com
0.0.0.0 v10.vortex-win.data.microsoft.com
0.0.0.0 view.atdmt.com
0.0.0.0 vortex-sandbox.data.microsoft.com
0.0.0.0 vortex-win.data.microsoft.com
0.0.0.0 vortex.data.microsoft.com
0.0.0.0 watson.live.com
0.0.0.0 watson.microsoft.com
0.0.0.0 watson.ppe.telemetry.microsoft.com
0.0.0.0 watson.telemetry.microsoft.com
0.0.0.0 watson.telemetry.microsoft.com.nsatc.net
0.0.0.0 wes.df.telemetry.microsoft.com
0.0.0.0 win10.ipv6.microsoft.com
```

Comment: Are you allowed to use wildcards? I do not see such in the [man](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/hosts.5.html) page.

Comment: Wildcards are not allowed in the hosts file. You would need to set up a dns server.